# "Games for [some kind of player]"/"Games with [some kind of property]" questioins

Tags: discussion, questions

There's a certain type of question that isn't quite a [recommendation question](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66/recommend-a-game-questions), which have been discussed, but which are instead soliciting a list of games with a certain property or set of properties. I've asked a few of these questions myself, as have other people. For example:

- [Good games for playing in a bar](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/529/good-games-for-playing-in-a-bar)
- [Deepest games in the past century](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/343/deepest-games-in-the-past-century)
- [Other “network building” style games, like Hackers and Illuminati?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/479/other-network-building-style-games-like-hackers-and-illuminati)
- [Games with features like Battlestar Galactica's “Traitor” Mechanic?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/92/games-with-features-like-battlestar-galacticas-traitor-mechanic)

Even though I've asked a few of these, I'm starting to wonder if they're a good fit for BCG.SE. I think I started asking them out of an old habit from when I contributed to [BoardGameGeek](http://boardgamegeek.com/), as these questions are good starting points for a GeekList. The question is, do these list type questions fit here too, or should they stay on BGG?

When voting on games in these sorts of lists, are you voting on how much you like the game, or how well the game fits the theme of the list? Does it ever make sense to accept an answer in this sort of list? Should people be doing one game per answer, or trying to do one comprehensive answer like my [answer to the “Traitor”](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/92/games-with-features-like-battlestar-galacticas-traitor-mechanic/260#260) question?

It's also hard to say how you would categorize these, if they're not appropriate. They aren't exactly subjective; if the criteria are clear, it can be quite clear cut which games fit and which ones don't. They aren't off-topic; they're definitely about board games. They are real questions; when I ask these, it's because I want to know the answer, I want to know which games fit. So according to those criteria, these should be fine, but there's still a certain way in which they don't quite seem to fit, as they're asking for a list of answers, not a single answer.

Answer (score 5):

I think these questions CAN be valuable, and shouldn't be prohibited up front.  I'd guess some of them will not be valuable and will get closed, as well.

I view an upvote on one of these lists as "Yes, I like this game and it fits in this list".  Maybe that's not what everyone intended but that's how I've been reading it.

For that reason, I think one-game-per-answer works pretty well also.

I'm not sure how to keep them from running out of control (if you will) but for now I support these questions.

Comment: I agree that a one-game-per-answer system would work well. And, I think that questions like these should be community questions.

Answer (score 3):

While I have answered a few of these (such as ["Board Games for Two People"](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/212/board-games-for-two-players/214#214)), they're extremely subjective and difficult to answer.  I know all of my downvotes have come from my answer in that one thread, for what I thought was a good answer.

I feel that they certainly have value, though, and are great questions for the community (emphasis on community) -- they would be best suited as community wiki questions.  Now if only they hadn't made community wikis a moderator-only feature...