# Does accepting answers and offering bounties on survey questions make sense?

Tags: discussion

The community (via meta) seems to have decided that certain subjective, survey-type questions are allowed on the site:

- [recommend a game](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66/recommend-a-game-questions)
- [recommend a game #2](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298/should-we-allow-game-recommendations-answer-yes-but-read-on)
- [games like __](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/412/do-we-want-game-like-questions).

Furthermore, we have several well-formed questions of this type on the site that seemed to have worked well and have prompted interesting answers:

- [What cooperative board games are there that I could safely play with my wife?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/9/what-cooperative-board-games-are-there-that-i-could-safely-play-with-my-wife)
- [Board games for two players](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/212/board-games-for-two-players)
- [Games to Introduce “Non-Gamers” to Board Gaming? (Gateway Games)](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/3368/games-to-introduce-non-gamers-to-board-gaming-gateway-games)

So this question isn't a rehash of this decision, but I am wondering if the Stack Exchange concepts of an **accepted** answer and **bounties** make sense for surveys.

For example, a bounty has been placed on [Recommended Axis & Allies alternative rules / variations?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/1032/recommended-axis-allies-alternative-rules-variations). But a question like this functions on Stack Exchange by putting each major idea in its own answer and letting people vote for the ideas they like the best (i.e. the votes serve as the community's recommendations). In this context, the concept of a single best answer doesn't make sense--and by extention offering an bounty to encourage the OP to accept an answer doesn't make sense to me.

Do people agree, and if so **is there anything that should be done to discourage accepting answers and offering bounties on survey questions?**

Answer (score 2):

If accepted and bounties don't make sense on survey questions, then perhaps we should ask if they should be here at all.

My [answer](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/412/do-we-want-game-like-questions/413#413) to the most recent such meta question has received the most upvotes.  [Jeff's answer](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/412/do-we-want-game-like-questions/415#415) should also be read.

We know such questions get a lot of upvotes, but that doesn't mean that they are quality questions.  Asking people to vote for list items like individual games instead of complete solid answers does not lead to greatness on the SE platform as it distorts reputation.  That accepting questions and bounties don't work well either is just another symptom.